# Typescript recurse through object and change type of key

Tags: typescript, types

I'm making a function that recursively curries all functions in an object. I used ts-toolbelt for the curry type but I'm not sure how to do the return type of the function. Here's what I have so far:

```
const curryAll = (obj, val) => { // what is the return type?
    return Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(obj).map((k, v) => {
            if (typeof v === 'function') {
                return [k, curry(v, val)]
            } else {
                return [k, curryAll(v)]
            }
        })
    )
}
```

`{ [key in keyof T]: F.Curry<key> }` doesn't work because it doesn't recurse and I'm stuck on what to do next.

Comment: Please make this a [mre] by either removing the ts-toolbelt dependency, or by explicitly adding the relevant function and type definitions so that people can paste the code into a standalone IDE and get to work on it.  Ideally the dependency should just be removed.

Comment: Note that the `key` in `{[key in keyof T]: XXX<key>}` is unconventionally named.  That's a type parameter, and thus conventionally it would be an uppercase single letter like `K` or possibly an UpperPascalCase keyword like `Key`.  If you name it `key` it looks like a dummy key name, which it is not.  There is no key named `key`.  Please consider replacing with something convetnional like `K` so as to not distract from your issue.

Comment: Shouldn't your inner `curryAll` call take two arguments? What happened to `val`?  Shouldn't you not recurse downward if the value is a non-object?  Don't you need a third clause in there to prevent you from trying to "curry" `string`s and `number`s?  Shouldn't you be writing `([k, v]) => ... `instead of `(k, v) => ...`?  I don't understand what you're doing, I guess.    Are you sure your implementation is correct at runtime?

Comment: So, [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w23a1N) might work for you.  But I had to provide `curry`'s implementation and typing (which might not be the same as yours) and I had to fix a number of errors in your implementation of `curryAll` to get it working reasonably.  If this meets your needs I can write up an error, but first you (or I, if you allow it) should [edit] the question to use my `curry` and error fixes, just without the typing, perhaps like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbn02m).  Let me know.